# dual marching cubes table

Tags: c#, marching-cubes

I've just finished building these tables for dual marching cubes (by Nielson).
VerticesNumberTable contains the length of the array of vertices to create for each Voxel (1 to 4 internal vertices), while EdgesTable is used to assign every one of these vertices to the right edges of the voxel, in order to use them to calculate internal vertex position and normal.
Edgetable works  a little like triTable for original marching Cubes algorithm. Every set of edges is separated by the next set by a -1. The list is closed by -2, so this value can be used to break a cycle.

```
#region EdgesTable

    public static int[,] EdgesTable = new int[256, 16]
    {
            {-2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 8, 3, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {0, 1, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {1, 3, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {1, 2, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
            {0, 8, 3, -1, 1, 2, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {9, 0, 2, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {10, 2, 3, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {3, 11, 2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
            {0, 8, 11, 2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {1, 9, 0, -1, 2, 3, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {1, 2, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {1, 3, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
            {0, 1, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {0, 3, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {8, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
            {4, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {0, 3, 4, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 8, 4, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {1, 3, 4, 7, 9, -2, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},              
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 8, 4, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 0, 3, 7, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {0, 2, 10, 9, -1, 8, 7, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {8, 4, 7, -1, 3, 11, 2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {0, 2, 4, 7, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {9, 0, 1, -1, 8, 4, 7, -1, 2, 3, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},       
            {1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1-1, -1, -1, -1, -1},              
            {3, 11, 10, 1, -1, 8, 7, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {0, 1, 4, 7, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {4, 7, 8, -1, 0, 3, 11, 10, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {4, 7, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {9, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {9, 5, 4, -1, 0, 8, 3, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {0, 5, 4, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {1, 3, 4, 5, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 9, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {3, 0, 8, -1, 1, 2, 10, -1, 4, 9, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},       
            {0, 2, 4, 5, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {9, 5, 4, -1, 2, 3, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {9, 4, 5, -1, 0, 2, 11, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {3, 11, 2, -1, 0, 4, 5, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {3, 11, 10, 1, -1, 9, 4, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {4, 9, 5, -1, 0, 1, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {5, 4, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},  
            {5, 7, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {0, 3, 5, 7, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {0, 1, 5, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {1, 5, 3, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 8, 7, 5, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 0, 3, 7, 5, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},      
            {0, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {2, 3, 5, 7, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {2, 3, 11, -1, 5, 7, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},            
            {0, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {2, 3, 11, -1, 0, 1, 5, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},      
            {1, 2, 5, 7, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},   
            {3, 11, 10, 1, -1, 8, 7, 5, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},     
            {0, 1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {0, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
            {5, 7, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 6, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 8, -1, 10, 5, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 10, 5, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {10, 5, 6, -1, 3, 8, 9, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 5, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 8, -1, 1, 2, 6, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 5, 6, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {3, 11, 2, -1, 10, 6, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {10, 5, 6, -1, 0, 8, 2, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {3, 11, 2, -1, 0, 1, 9, -1, 10, 5, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {10, 5, 6, -1, 11, 2, 8, 9, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 5, 6, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 5, 6, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 6, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {8, 7, 4, -1, 5, 6, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 6, 10, -1, 0, 3, 4, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {10, 5, 6, -1, 1, 9, 0, -1, 8, 7, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {10, 5, 6, -1, 7, 4, 9, 1, 3, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {8, 7, 4, -1, 1, 2, 6, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 7, 4, -1, 1, 2, 6, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {8, 7, 4, -1, 0, 9, 2, 5, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {3, 11, 2, -1, 5, 6, 10, -1, 8, 7, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {10, 5, 6, -1, 0, 2, 11, 7, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {3, 11, 2, -1, 0, 1, 9, -1, 10, 5, 6, -1, 8, 7, 4, -2},
            {10, 5, 6, -1, 7, 4, 11, 2, 1, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {8, 7, 4, -1, 3, 11, 6, 5, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {8, 7, 4, -1, 6, 5, 9, 0, 11, 3, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},             
            {4, 6, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 8, -1, 9, 10, 6, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 4, 6, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 6, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 8, -1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 4, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 6, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 2, 3, -1, 9, 4, 10, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 11, 8, -1, 9, 4, 6, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 11, -1, 0, 1, 4, 6, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 4, 6, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 6, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 6, 7, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 6, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 6, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {3, 11, 2, -1, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {3, 11, 2, -1, 8, 7, 0, 1, 10, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 6, 7, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {6, 7, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 0, 3, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 0, 9, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 1, 3, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 1, 2, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 1, 2, 10, -1, 0, 3, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 0, 9, 10, 2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 6, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 6, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 3, 2, 6, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 6, 7, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 6, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 4, 6, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 8, 4, 11, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 8, 4, 6, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 0, 3, 11, 6, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 9, 10, 2, -1, 8, 4, 11, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 6, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 4, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 6, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 4, 6, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 6, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {6, 7, 11, -1, 4, 5, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {6, 7, 11, -1, 4, 5, 9, -1, 0, 3, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 1, 0, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 8, 3, 1, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 4, 5, 9, -1, 1, 2, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 4, 5, 9, -1, 1, 2, 10, -1, 0, 3, 8, -2},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 0, 2, 10, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {11, 7, 6, -1, 8, 3, 2, 10, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 5, 9, -1, 3, 2, 6, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 5, 9, -1, 2, 0, 8, 7, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {3, 2, 6, 7, -1, 0, 1, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {9, 4, 5, -1, 1, 10, 6, 7, 3, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {9, 4, 5, -1, 6, 10, 1, 0, 8, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 6, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 5, 6, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 5, 6, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 9, 5, 6, 11, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 10, -1, 9, 0, 3, 11, 6, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 5, 6, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 5, 6, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 6, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 7, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 7, 10, 11, -1, 0, 3, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 7, 10, 11, -1, 0, 1, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 7, 10, 11, -1, 3, 8, 9, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 5, 7, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 5, 7, 11, -1, 0, 3, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 5, 7, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 7, 3, 2, 10, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 5, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 5, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 5, 7, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {5, 7, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 5, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 8, 11, 10, 4, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 4, 5, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -1, 8, 3, 2, 10, 5, 4, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 5, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 4, 5, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 5, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 7, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 8, -1, 10, 9, 4, 7, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 4, 7, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, -1, 0, 3, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 4, 7, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 4, 7, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 4, 7, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {4, 7, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {8, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 9, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 8, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 10, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 8, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 8, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 11, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {2, 3, 8, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 2, 9, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 2, 10, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {1, 3, 8, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 1, 9, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {0, 3, 8, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
            {-2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
    };

    #endregion

    public static int[] VerticesNumberTable = new int[256]
    {
        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,
        1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1,
        1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1,
        2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
    };


public static void Polygonise(Voxel voxel, float isolevel)
    {
        int cubeIndex = voxel.CaseNumber;

        if (cubeIndex > 0 & cubeIndex < 255)
        {
            Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[VerticesNumberTable[cubeIndex]];
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                vertices[i] = new Vertex();
            }

            int v = 0;

            for (int e = 0; e < EdgesTable.GetLength(1); e++)
            {
                if (EdgesTable[cubeIndex, e] == -2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (EdgesTable[cubeIndex, e] == -1)
                {
                    v++;
                }
                else
                {                    
                    vertices[v].Edges.Add(voxel.Edges[EdgesTable[cubeIndex, e]]);
                    voxel.Edges[EdgesTable[cubeIndex, e]].ConnectTo(vertices[v]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Original work:
http://vis.computer.org/vis2004/DVD/vis/papers/nielson2.pdf

Comment: is the above code workable?

Comment: I’m voting to close this post because there is no any question in the text.